# Unique constraint being violated on the wrong column when using SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to use `SqlBulkCopy` as a way of doing multiple INSERTs at once but for some reason, I'm getting a unique constraint violation when running `WriteToServer(DataTable)`. The odd thing about this `SqlException` is it's saying that .

My table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Product (
  ID   INT IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  Name NVARCHAR(450) UNIQUE NOT NULL, -- Unique constraint being called
  BulkInsertID NCHAR(6) -- Column the constraint is being called on
);
```

The only reason I can think of as to why this is happening is because I mixed up the column names when assigning them inside the `DataColumn`s but I checked them multiple times and I cannot find any issues with them.

[Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

```
class Program
{
    private static SqlConnection connection;
    private static string connectionURL = "Server=ASUS-X750JA\\DIRECTORY;Database=directory;Integrated Security=True;";
    private static Random _random = new Random();

    public static SqlConnection openConnection()
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection(connectionURL);
        connection.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Opened connection to DB");
        return connection;
    }

    public static void closeConnection()
    {
        connection.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Closed connection to DB");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> productNames = new List<string>();
        productNames.Add("Diamond");
        productNames.Add("Gold");
        productNames.Add("Silver");
        productNames.Add("Platinum");
        productNames.Add("Pearl");
        addProducts(productNames);
    }

    private static void addProducts(List<string> productNames)
    {
        const string tableName = "Product";
        DataTable table = new DataTable(tableName);

        string bulkInsertID;
        do
        {
            bulkInsertID = generateID();
        } while (isDuplicateBulkInsertID(tableName, bulkInsertID));

        DataColumn nameColumn = new DataColumn("Name");
        nameColumn.Unique = true;
        nameColumn.AllowDBNull = false;

        DataColumn bulkInsertIDColumn = new DataColumn("BulkInsertID");
        bulkInsertIDColumn.Unique = false;
        bulkInsertIDColumn.AllowDBNull = true;

        table.Columns.Add(nameColumn);
        table.Columns.Add(bulkInsertIDColumn);

        foreach (string productName in productNames)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            row[nameColumn] = productName;
            row[bulkInsertIDColumn] = bulkInsertID;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        using (SqlConnection connection = openConnection())
        {
            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = table.TableName;
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates random 6-character string but it's not like GUID so may need to check for duplicates
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string generateID()
    {
        char[] _base62chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray();
        int length = 6;

        var sb = new StringBuilder(length);

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            sb.Append(_base62chars[_random.Next(62)]);

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static bool isDuplicateBulkInsertID(string tableName, string bulkInsertID)
    {
        string query = string.Format("SELECT BulkInsertID FROM {0} WHERE BulkInsertID = @bulkinsertid", tableName);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, openConnection());
        SqlParameter bulkInsertIDParam = new SqlParameter("@bulkinsertid", SqlDbType.NChar, bulkInsertID.Length);
        bulkInsertIDParam.Value = bulkInsertID;

        command.Parameters.Add(bulkInsertIDParam);
        command.Prepare();
        Task<SqlDataReader> asyncTask = command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
        SqlDataReader reader = asyncTask.Result;
        bool isDuplicate = reader.HasRows;

        closeConnection();
        return isDuplicate;
    }
}
```

[image]

The unique constraint shown in the screenshot belongs to the `Name` column but the duplicate key value is being sent to the `BulkInsertID` column and I don't know why the error is being thrown.

EDIT: I just changed my schema to use `uniqueidentifier` as the `bulkInsertID` column and changed `row[bulkInsertIDColumn] = bulkInsertID` to `row[bulkInsertIDColumn] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`. When I reran my code, I found that the generated GUID ran but when I looked at the table, the GUID was in the name column. So I can conclude it's not a server issue but a problem in the program.

Comment: looks to me as if the error message is telling you exactly what the issue is ..have you tried debugging the code and seeing where you're adding the duplicate key value?

Comment: Yes, it's the bulkInsertID string variable which I already knew but what I don't understand why the `BulkInsertID` column would be saying the UNIQUE constraint is being violated even though that column doesn't have a UNIQUE constraint on it.

Comment: "Every time you do new Random() it is initialized using the clock. This means that in a tight loop you get the same value lots of times. You should keep a single Random instance and keep using Next on the same instance." http://stackoverflow.com/a/768001/43846

Comment: @stuartd Not a duplicate because the `Random` object isn't causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have a identity column bulk insert is trying to insert `nameColumn` in to `ID` (and ignoring it because the column is a identity column) and `bulkInsertIDColumn` in to `Name`. Just add the following to your insert to tell it to go to the correct columns.

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
{
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name"); //NEW
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("BulkInsertID", "BulkInsertID"); //NEW
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = table.TableName;
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
}
```

The other option is add a `ID` column to `table` and just don't put any values in it.

```
DataColumn idColumn = new DataColumn("ID");

DataColumn nameColumn = new DataColumn("Name");
//nameColumn.Unique = true; //SqlBulkCopy does not care about these settings.
//nameColumn.AllowDBNull = false;

DataColumn bulkInsertIDColumn = new DataColumn("BulkInsertID");
//bulkInsertIDColumn.Unique = false;
//bulkInsertIDColumn.AllowDBNull = true;

table.Columns.Add(ID);
table.Columns.Add(nameColumn);
table.Columns.Add(bulkInsertIDColumn);

foreach (string productName in productNames)
{
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    //We don't do anything with row[idColumn]
    row[nameColumn] = productName;
    row[bulkInsertIDColumn] = bulkInsertID;
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the column mappings! I had seen them in some tutorials but I figured they weren't so important because I would be using the column name inside `DataColumn`

Comment: Nah, if you don't specify anything SqlBulkInsert goes by column order.

Comment: @silverAndroid however, be aware like i mentioned in my deleted answer. If to copies of your program are running it is possible that two of them will generate the same `bulkInsertID` at the same time. If that is a issue for you, you may want to address it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's throwing `UNIQUE` constraint violation for column `BulkInsertID` though from posted table schema don't see it's marked with that constraint and in your code I see you have `bulkInsertIDColumn.Unique = false;`. Are you sure you are not setting it to `true` anywhere else.

BTW, to me looks it's throwing that exception cause you are trying to create a new instance of `Random()` in loop as seen below pointed code block

```
    do
    {
        bulkInsertID = generateID(); //calling method generateID
    } while (isDuplicateBulkInsertID(tableName, bulkInsertID));
```

Where as in `generateID()` you are creating new instance of Random class

```
public static string generateID()
{
   ........
    Random _random = new Random(); // creating new instance every time
```

Comment: Moved the new Random object outside of the method (as seen in my edited question) but it's still throwing the exception and the only place `Unique` is set to true is when I set `nameColumn.Unique = true`

Comment: @silverAndroid, consider using `GUID` instead for that `BulkInsertID` column.

Comment: Why would I need to? `generateID()` is not the one causing issues. The reason I chose to generate an ID instead of using GUID is because of the performance issues that come along with using it.

Comment: @silverAndroid *"The reason I chose to generate an ID instead of using GUID is because of the performance issues that come along with using it."*, what performance issues are you talking about? Your current method of generating a ID is going to have very poor performance due to the fact it has to hit the server over and over tried various id's to see if they are free.